# How can I made the QlikView's recent files menu (in the Windows bottom bar) show my currently used files?

Tags: windows-10

there are several files I use daily and I use to open them by right-clicking on the corresponding icon in the Windows bottom bar and selecting the file in the recently opened files menu.

This works well in Word, Excel and other programs but don't in QlikView. The menu opened when I right click the QlikView icon seems to be frozen, showing the files I used two or three months ago rather than the ones I opened yesterday and today.

Anyone knows how can I solve it? Many thanks in advance.